# where is the reverse light switch for polo mk5 2012

Tags: reverse-lights

Am told there is a reverse switch somewhere in the car which  turns on the tail revserse lights. Can anyone tell where this is so i can hook up my stereo to the switch for my my reverse cam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse switch is usually on the gearbox or the selector mechanism.

What i would look for is the wire going to the rear which feeds the reverse lights and tap into that. The camera will only need a signal, not a large current, however, you should still make sure to fit a suitable fuse.

Based on the comment:

I would just find the color of the wire at the rear light and cut into the wiring loom at a suitable point to get the same color wire - it will have a base color and a trace color. And, if you are color blind get help - one of my friends made such a mess of his motorbike wiring... He was a fantastic metal worker, but couldn't do colors - we had an agreement - very handy for beating out dents : wires I find easy...

Comment: It might be easier to start from the reverse lights themselves, rather than tracing a wire (which will probably be part of a wiring loom) back from the gearbox region.

Comment: I managed to trace the wire to front left passenger kick panel. It was black with a blue stripe

Comment: Excellent, hope it all finishes fine!